# Light green color meaning in Azure Devops Release Pipeline

Tags: colors, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

What does the light green fill color (or lack of light green fill color) mean in some successful deployment stages?

[https://dev.azure.com/[organization]/[project]/_release?_a=releases&view=mine&definitionId=20](https://dev.azure.com/%5Borganization%5D/%5Bproject%5D/_release?_a=releases&view=mine&definitionId=20)

Azure Devops Releases:

[image: Azure Devops Releases]

Answer (score 1):

The fill color represents the status of the latest run for that particular stage. The filling just makes it easier to locate the outcome of the latest run for a particular stage in the pipeline essentially.

Answer (score 1):

It represents the latest successful deployment of a stage that is an **agent job**. In the screenshot you provided the stage "ST Deploy..." was either changed to an [agentless job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agentless-tasks) or that stage in Release-12 was deployed before Release-11.